# Download compressed Byte[] to disk using ZipArchive C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a compressed byte array that I would like to download to the server as a .zip file. Using the following code, the file size shows the correct compressed size. But when I go to open the file it says the .zip file is invalid. Do I need to somehow set the content type to application/zip?

```
using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
var fileStream = new FileStream(@"<file directory\xxx.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            compressedStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Dispose();
```

File was zipped using the following snippet:

```
 byte[]? archiveFile = Array.Empty<byte>();
                        byte[]? fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);

                        using var archiveStream = new MemoryStream();

                        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                        {
                            var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file, CompressionLevel.SmallestSize);
                            using var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open();
                            zipStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                        }

                        archiveFile = archiveStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Where did the data come from? Are you sure it was compressed using the ZIP format?

Comment: Also, based on what you've shown here, there's no actual need for the `MemoryStream`. Is that different in the real scenario?

Comment: I zipped it up using ZipArchive. I edited the question to show how I zipped it.

Comment: File compression and stream compression work in very different ways, a stream is for compressing data during transmission so each transmission is compressed individually where as file compression compresses the entire file in one go,,as the file you have is already compressed you should just read the file directly to the transmission stream

Comment: Have you looked at both `archiveFile` and `fileBytes` to make sure they're making it through the connection unchanged?

Comment: Yes. I can extract the file and download it just fine back to it's original uncompressed version...However I need it to stay compressed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I'm busy building a service which retrieves files from an API as a byte[] with a list of properties, one of them containing the file extension. The service stores these files in a Blob Storage with the right file extension. To create a file from a byte[] you can use the following code.

> File.WriteAllBytes("somePath/file.zip", theByteArray);

File can be found in the given path. If you don't specify a specific path the file will be found in the somewhere inside the 'bin' folder of your project after a completed run. Remember to add the .zip extension in your first argument or else a file will be created with no extension. Pass in as a second argument a `byte[]`. Works fine here.